# How to create an auto executeable file of some terminal commands used for running any specific application

Tags: scripts, autostart, execute-command, additional-drivers, autorun

I have a .sh file of XP Pentablet driver
Every time I need to run these commands to run in order to run the program

```
$ cd /home/path/
$ chmod +x Pentablet_Driver.sh
$ sudo ./Pentablet_Driver
```

I wanna know, is there is anyway by which I create any *file that auto execute these commands* to run the application by it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An .sh file is already a shell script. It contains readable commands that are executed line by line.

Make your own shell script so you can execute all commands you want to run with a single command.

1. If you did not already, create a directory `bin` under the hidden directory `.local`. You can use your file manager. Set it to "show hidden files" so you can see the .local folder. Then log out and back in: Ubuntu is automatically configured to include `.local/bin` in the search PATH for executable files. (Note: if you prefer, it works the same with a folder `bin` directly in your home folder - the latter will not be hidden by default).
2. Open your text editor, and enter as the first line `#!/bin/bash`. On the subsequent lines, enter your three commands. As a detail, I can mention you that your second command, `chmod +x Pentablet_Driver.sh`, is not needed: this needs to be done only once, and not every time you run the script.
3. Save the file in the folder `.local/bin` under a name that you want to use to run the commands. Let us for example assume it will be `pentab`.
4. Now make that file executable. You can do this in your file manager from the dialog you get after right-clicking the file, then selecting "Properties". You could also use a command similar to the one I told you to leave out: `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/pentab`.

That is it. Now, typing the command `pentab` in the terminal or in the run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will run the three commands contained in the script (two only if you follog the advice to remove the second one).

Comment: It may be also just ~/bin instead of ~/.local/bin . It's also added automatically to PATH and ~/bin is a far more common Linux standard than ~/.local/bin .

Comment: I know it can be bin and I will add. The beauty of .local/bin is that the folder is hidden. Else, you end up with a "bin" folder next to the "snap" in your home folder. Ubuntu is configured to add one or the other, or both, to the path if they exist.